# Specify struct packing in C# implementation of a COM interface

Tags: com, interop, packing

Is it possible to specify the struct packing size in a C# implementation of a COM interface?

(I know how to do it when the struct is *defined* on the managed side, but my question is about when it's defined on the unmanaged side and *implemented* on the managed side.)

I've got a COM type library that defines a struct type and an interface method that returns an array of those structs. I've got a C# server and an unmanaged C++ server that both implement this interface, and a C++ client that consumes it. The C++ server and the C++ client both pack the struct to 4 bytes in a 32-bit build, and to 8 bytes in a 64-bit build.

But the C# server always packs to 4 bytes, regardless of platform (x86, x64, AnyCPU). Is this normal? Can it be overridden?

The struct looks like this:

```
typedef [v1_enum] enum { blah... } HandlerPriority;
struct HandlerInfo { BSTR MessageName; HandlerPriority Priority; }
```

The Visual Studio C++ and MIDL compilers use a default packing of /Zp8. In a 32-bit build both members of the struct are 4 bytes wide, and so they are not padded. In a 64-bit build the string pointer is 8 bytes and the enum 4, so the enum is padded. Naturally, this causes problems when the C# client sends unpadded data.

I can fix (work around?) the problem by specifying /Zp4 to remove the padding, and everything seems to work fine. But I wonder whether that's the best solution.

I imagine the default packing is /Zp8 for performance reasons only. As I understand it, by default on x64 the hardware traps and handles alignment exceptions and so at least we won't crash. And in this particular situation I don't care about the performance penalty because the interface function is only called at system startup. And even if I did care I might still accept it as the cost of COM/.NET interop. But I'm a little uneasy because it feels wrong (coming from a C++ background, I suppose.)

On the other hand, if it's simply not possible to change the packing on the managed side, then I'll live with it.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: After lots of digging around... It seems that the .NET DLL will indeed pack to whatever size it's told to. It gets the packing size from the tlbimp-generated RCW that wraps the COM type library containing the struct definition. Using tlbimp, if I say /platform:x64 then the RCW says ".pack 8", but if I say /platform:agnostic then it says ".pack 4". I do want /platform:agnostic, I just want it to pack to 8 bytes on both platforms. The solution is to decompile the RCW, change the .pack directive in the generated source code, and recompile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The packing size is specified by tlbimp.exe in the RCW that it generates. If I pass /platform:x64 on the command line then the RCW says ".pack 8", but if I say /platform:x86 or /platform:agnostic then it says ".pack 4".

I do want /platform:agnostic so that I can use the same RCW on both 32- and 64-bit platforms. Normally I find that AnyCPU is more trouble than it's worth, but this project is an SDK and I don't want to impose my views on that topic on my users if I can avoid it.

I also want 8-byte packing because 4-byte packing on x64 can be expensive. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290049%28v=vs.71%29.aspx.

The solution I've settled on is to decompile the RCW, change the .pack directive in the generated source code, and recompile.

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar problem, some structures, when passed from C# to C++ through COM, worked in 32-bit COM, but were corrupted in 64-bit.

I spent some time researching and this thread was also helpful.

It looks like TlbImp.exe tries to pack every structure as 4-bytes aligned, and only if it does not meet certain criteria, packs a structure as 8-bytes aligned. It does this both for 32-bit and 64-bit mode.

But it has some strange rules to determine it. What I found, for x64, if a structure only has 4-byte integers, enums and safearrays, it is packed as 4-bytes aligned, otherwise it is packed as 8-bytes alinged. For x86, a structure is only packed as 8-bytes aligned when a 64-bit variable is present in it, otherwise, it is packed as 4-bytes aligned. Maybe there are other variants, but this is only what we found in our product.

C++, on the other hand, with its default packing (8 bytes), packs each type aligned by a minimum of 8 bytes or the size of a member.

So, for 32-bit mode, there is no problem since there is no difference between 4 and 8 bytes aligning if there are no 8-bytes sized members in the structure. But if there are, TlbImp.exe packs the structure as 8-bytes aligned, so this also matches C++.

For 64-bit mode, however, there is a case, when a structure has 8-bytes member, but is packed as 4-bytes aligned. In our case it is when it has SAFEARRAYs. If a structure has only SAFEARRAYs and 32-(or less?)-bit integers, it is packed as 4-bytes aligned for x64 platform. But, since SAFEARRAY is a 64-bit pointer on C++ side, it is packed there differently, padding areas before SAFEARRAYs to 8-byte margins.  I don't know, whether it is a bug or a feature.

To fix this problem, we injected C++ pragma pack instructions before such 4-bytes aligned structures in 64-bit. We identified such structures by decompiling the assembly with ildasm.exe and searching for ".pack 4" (thanks Ciaran for the hint).

Such a structure in IDL looks like this:

```
   // some of our structures must be 4 bytes aligned because TlbImp packs them this way
   cpp_quote("#pragma pack(push, 4)")

   typedef [uuid("3F253C09-D7F5-3BE-9698-00CB49A7005C"),
         helpstring("SOME structure"),
         version(5.1)] struct SOMEINFO
   {
      long ItemsActive;
      SAFEARRAY(BSTR) ItemIDs; // without pack 4 it would be 8 bytes aligned on x64
      SAFEARRAY(long) ItemRuns;
      SAFEARRAY(SOMEFunctions) ItemFuncList;
      SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) ItemFactors;
      long MIndex;
      SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) DeltaItems;
   } SOMEINFO;

   cpp_quote("#pragma pack(pop)") // matches pack(push, 4) placed before the structure
```

Alternatively, we could just add to this structure a 64-bit dummy variable, or BSTR to force it into .pack 8, but we didn't want to change the interface.

So, we are basically following TlbImp it its strange logic. But there are just a few of such structures in our code, so, it is fine for us. This way, both 32 and 64 bit COM pass all the structures correctly.

Comment: Hi Vladimir. I was very keen not modify the internals of our product just to accommodate the quirks of an automatically generated interop assembly. In fact, I might even have preferred to generate the interop assembly manually, if necessary. Looks like you're not so stubborn as I am!

Answer (score 2):

Will the Pack attribute work here for you? Here's an example from my own code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
{
   public int privilegeCount;
   public LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES privileges;
}
```

I have used this when configuring services and I use the Pack=1 attribute to align the privileges field exactly after the privilegeCount field when marshalling this struct to Win32.

Comment: The struct is defined in COM, not in .NET, and so there's no opportunity to do it just as you suggest. But my solution of decompile/alter/recompile the tlbimp-generated RCW achieves the same thing. I do that in a post-build script so it's convenient. Thanks all the same.

Comment: I am confused (albeit it doesn't take a whole pile).  A struct defined in COM and not in .NET is the case in the above example (you still have to surface the struct in managed code to use it, no?) Your question asks '...if it's simply not possible to change the packing on the managed side...' See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922785 for more info. Maybe I'm at total cross purposes with what you're trying to achieve but this was something I had to do before

Comment: You're using P/Invoke, which requires you to handle the low-level details and thus affords you no type safety. From a .NET perspective your TOKEN_PRIVILEGES struct is not related to the Win32 API TOKEN_PRIVILEGES in any way; they are not the same type, although they do happen to have the same binary layout. I'm using COM interop, and while ultimately the same marshaling issues must be addressed the .NET type library importer (tlbimp.exe) does all that dirty work for me, and it gives me type safety. Well, not quite all the dirty work, which was the point of my question.

Comment: Of course, re-reading your question now what you're asking makes sense. Unfortunately I just saw the words 'pack' and 'align' and thought 'I've done something like that recently enough'. You're calling COM components - not native DLLs - and you appear to have a satisfactory workaround already. Perhaps promote your own comment to an answer?

Comment: I hear ya. Thanks for your response all the same. I enjoy learning stuff, and even just having to explain myself to you improves my understanding. I didn't want to answer the question myself because I was hoping that someone might give me a better answer, but maybe you're right. Could have saved you some time - sorry about that.